# Creating a column to be enum with Zend Framework 2 Ddl - Using Zend Framework 2, not version 1.x

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I was wondering how to create a enum column with Zend Framework's Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl. I've looked on other sites but without luck. For example, here is what I am trying to do:

```
$table = new Ddl\CreateTable("table_name");
$table->addColumn([enum type here);
```

Does Zend Framework 2 support the enum type for database columns? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Mysql get ENUM values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112490/zend-mysql-get-enum-values)